# How to broil a rack of goat ribs

Tags: ribs, broiling, goat

It's football playoff time, and I have two racks of goat ribs. My cooking plan is to wrap the ribs in foil and broil them. Any recommendations about what to do with them first, and what to put in the foil with them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am assuming that you have actual goat ribs, like pork ribs, and not a rack of goat chops.  I had a full goat breast that I just cooked them the other day.  If you just broil them as you describe they will be tasty...and tough...and greasy.

You want to treat these like pork ribs, needing a slow cook.  I first smoke my ribs, then braise them, then finish them under the broiler with a thinned sauce.  [Here's the whole process in great detail at cookloose.com](http://cookloose.com/index.php/Recipes/BarbecueRibs)

Unless you are saying broil as a means of describing putting them on a grill, note that wrapping the ribs in foil before broiling defeats the purpose.  Broiling is directional heat...heatfrom a direction.  Wrapping them in foil reflects the direct heat away.

However, your method is, almost, correct.  You DO want to wrap the ribs in foil with a little liquid (beer?), maybe some garlic and a bay leaf, or do a full rub, and then put them in the oven at low heat for a braise.  This will cause the meat and connective tissue to get soft and yummy.  THEN pour off the liquid, open the foil and slip under the broiler to give them a crusty finish.  Brush with a sauce or not, as you wish.

So...slow cook in liquid...broil to finish, but not wrapped in foil for the broil.

Comment: I'll confirm that these are ribs, not chops.

Answer (score 2):

Again, assuming they're similar to pork ribs: I'd cook them in Lager until soft - test with a fork every now and then - then leave them in the liquid until cold and for as long as you like - I regularly leave my pork ribs in the beer for a day or two. Then take them out, drain them, brush them with sauce and broil them until hot and crispy on the outside.